# Map fragment on Navigation Drawer cant access current location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I can't access my current location with this. I don't know what is the problem but. Every time I go to the map fragment on my navigation bar I can't see my current location.

Here is my code..

**LanlordMapFragment.java**

```
public class LanlordMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;


public LanlordMapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lanlord_map, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("MAP");

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("My Location"));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
      return;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced such type of problem:

Please, try to add the piece of code to your **public View onCreateView(..){}**

```
 MapView m = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.source);

 m.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 0):

//try this code

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng)
                {

                }
            });

     GetCurrentLocation location = new GetCurrentLocation(getActivity(), new GeocodingNotifier<Location>()
            {
                @Override
                public void GeocodingDetails(Location geocodeLatLng) {
                    if (geocodeLatLng != null) {
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(geocodeLatLng.getLatitude(), geocodeLatLng.getLongitude()), 14f));
                    }
                    else {
                        // shaow erroe message
                    }
                }
            });
```

///  class to GetCurrentLocation

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class GetCurrentLocation implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = GetCurrentLocation.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;
    public static Location mLastLocation=null;
    public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GeocodingNotifier mNotifier;
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters


    Activity mContext;

    public GetCurrentLocation(Activity mContext, GeocodingNotifier mNotifier) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mNotifier = mNotifier;

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // Building the GoogleApi client
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            createLocationRequest();
        }
    }

    public void setOnResultsListener(GeocodingNotifier mNotifier) {
        this.mNotifier = mNotifier;
    }

    /**
     * Method to display the location on UI
     */
    private void displayLocation() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();


        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to toggle periodic location updates
     */
    private void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {

            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

            // Starting the location updates
            startLocationUpdates();

            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates started!");

        } else {

            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

            // Stopping the location updates
            stopLocationUpdates();

            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates stopped!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating google api client object
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Creating location request object
     */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);

        displayLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Method to verify google play services on the device
     */
    public boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, mContext,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Starting the location updates
     */
    public void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    /**
     * Stopping location updates
     */
    public void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // Once connected with google api, get the location
        displayLocation();
        startLocationUpdates();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Assign the new location
        mLastLocation = location;
        mNotifier.GeocodingDetails(mLastLocation);
        displayLocation();
        stopLocationUpdates();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Comment: where will i gonna put this?

Comment: i still got an error sir 
here 
 GetCurrentLocation location = new GetCurrentLocation(getActivity(), new GeocodingNotifier<Location>()

Comment: i have added GetCurrentLocation Class in the answer use that class also.

Comment: how can i use that sir?? sorry i am really a newbie on the development :( should i create a new class for GetCurrentLocation? i created one but still to many errors :(

Comment: the problem now is i need to create class for GeocodingNotifier and LocationRequest